# Como chamo uma função de outro arquivo javascript na minha api com express

Tags: javascript, express.js, route

Preciso chamar uma função dentro de uma rota `'/teste'` so que a função esta dentro de outro arquivo js.

Função que quero chamar dentro do arquivo ***gatopreto.js***

```
function teste (){
    return 'funciona'
}
```

Onde eu estou chamando ela:

```
routes.get('/teste',(req,res)=>{
    var resposta =  teste();
    return res.send(resposta);
});
```

Erro exibido quando eu entro na rota /teste:

> **ReferenceError: teste is not defined**

Answer (score 2):

Existem algumas maneiras de fazer o que deseja.

Usando `exports` e o `module exports` em conjunto com o `require`.

Supondo que temos a seguinte estrutura de pastas:

```
.
├── _services
│   └── gatopreto.js
└── _routes
    └── index.js
```

Supondo que o conteúdo que postou no arquivo `gatopreto.js` então poderia usar exports nomeados da seguinte forma:

```
teste = () => {
    return 'funciona'
}
module.exports = { teste };
```

Outra maneira equivalente de exportar esta função é utilizando a estratégia do default export:

```
exports.teste = () => {
    return 'funciona'
}
```

Depois no arquivo de rotas antes de usar a função declarada basta importar esta função utilizando o comando `require`:

***routes/index.js***

```
const gp = require('../service/gatopreto.js');

routes.get('/saida', (req, res) => {

    var resposta =  gp.teste();
    return res.send(resposta);
});
```

Para aprender mais sobre módulos e detalhadamente o seu funcionamento, veja na [`documentação do nodejs`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports_shortcut).